# python selenium could not locate link element contain /

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Python 3.10,
I try to locate the href element of two sites from google search:
[www.siteA.com](http://www.siteA.com) and [www.siteB.com/bb](http://www.siteB.com/bb)

```
element = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//a[contains(@href, "www.siteA.com")]')
```

works but

```
element = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//a[contains(@href, "www.siteB.com/bb")]')
```

doesn't work.

I tried:

```
element = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//a[contains(@href, "www.siteB.com")]')
```

it works??? how to solve this problem if I want to have the element with whole link? I tried to put `\` before `/bb` but failed

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Which site? Maybe your url have a redirect?

Comment: @user5151477 what's your actual code snippet? Please let know in the ask.
Also, will be good if you can breif about `doesn't work` what kind of error you're hitting on the execution?

Comment: you can just search metal shops in us. I found that for those sites with <a href> element like www.siteA.com, www.siteC.com, my code can locate those site correctly.  i tried to locate the <a href> element with a slash  inside the link, www.siteB.com/bb, then the code fails to locate the item. I tried to locate it with part of the link, www.siteB.com, then the code can locate the item correctly. I know it is not necessary to fixate on this little problem but I need some expert to confirm this is a bug or what is the problem inside so other people could avoid this trouble.